# Firestore not retrieving certain fields from document

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a recycler in a fragment to show documents from a collection in firestore, the problem is, it is only retrieving certain fields from the document, it looks like it is ignoring some of the other Setter fields from model class, this is the error i get:

> W/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzko]: No setter/field for sabado found on
> class
> com.example.denilsondasilva.iasdmt.com.example.denilsondasilva.com.example.denilsondasilva.MODELS.ModelProgramas

now here is my model class:

```
public class ModelProgramas {

    public ModelProgramas() {
    }

    public ModelProgramas(String sabado, String evento, String responsavel, String data, String horario) {
        this.sabado = sabado;
        this.evento = evento;
        this.responsavel = responsavel;
        this.data = data;
        this.horario = horario;
    }

    public String getSabado() {
        return sabado;
    }

    public void setSabado(String sabado) {
        this.sabado = sabado;
    }

    public String getEvento() {
        return evento;
    }

    public void setEvento(String evento) {
        this.evento = evento;
    }

    public String getResponsavel() {
        return responsavel;
    }

    public void setResponsavel(String responsavel) {
        this.responsavel = responsavel;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getHorario() {
        return horario;
    }

    public void setHorario(String horario) {
        this.horario = horario;
    }

    private String sabado;
    private String evento;
    private String responsavel;
    private String data;
    private String horario;
}
```

I have created an EMPTY CONSTRUCTOR for the class, I have created CONSTRUCTORS for the variables and also Getters and Setters, and I have seen previous questions with the same issue so I know my GETTERS AND SETTERS and variables were created properly. variables Lower-case, getters and setters starting with Upper-case. and the Strings in the firestore document are same as the created variables

here is my adapter:

```
public class PROGRAMASrecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PROGRAMASrecyclerAdapter.Programasholder> {

    Context ctx;
    private List<ModelProgramas> Progs_list;

    public PROGRAMASrecyclerAdapter(List<ModelProgramas> progs_list) {
        this.Progs_list = progs_list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Programasholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ctx = parent.getContext();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.programas_list_item,parent,false);
        return new Programasholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Programasholder holder, int position) {

        final String sabado = Progs_list.get(position).getSabado();
        holder.setSabado(sabado);

        String evento = Progs_list.get(position).getEvento();
        holder.setEvento(evento);

        String responsavel = Progs_list.get(position).getResponsavel();
        holder.setResponsavel(responsavel);

        String data = Progs_list.get(position).getData();
        holder.setData(data);

        String horario = Progs_list.get(position).getHorario();
        holder.setHorario(horario);

        holder.mcardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, sabado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Progs_list.size();
    }

    public class Programasholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        View mView;
        private TextView Sabadotxt;
        private TextView Eventotxt;
        private TextView Responsaveltxt;
        private TextView DatadoEventotxt;
        private TextView Horariotxt;
        private CardView mcardView;

        public Programasholder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

            mcardView = mView.findViewById(R.id.listCard_Programas);
        }

        public void setSabado(String sabado){
            Sabadotxt = mView.findViewById(R.id.Prog_sabadotxt);
            Sabadotxt.setText(sabado);
        }

        public void setEvento(String evento){
            Eventotxt = mView.findViewById(R.id.Prog_eventotxt);
            Eventotxt.setText(evento);
        }

        public void setResponsavel(String responsavel){
            Responsaveltxt = mView.findViewById(R.id.Prog_responsaveltxt);
            Responsaveltxt.setText(responsavel);
        }

        public void setData(String data){
            DatadoEventotxt = mView.findViewById(R.id.Prog_datadoEventotxt);
            DatadoEventotxt.setText(data);
        }

        public void setHorario(String horario){
            Horariotxt = mView.findViewById(R.id.Prog_horariotxt);
            Horariotxt.setText(horario);
        }
    }
}
```

I even created an on click listener on the cardview to display the retrieved string "sabado" to see if the problem is on the Viewholder class, but it is RETURNING NULL

and here is my fragment class:

```
public class ProgramasFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<ModelProgramas> Progs_List;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    PROGRAMASrecyclerAdapter programaSrecyclerAdapter;


    public ProgramasFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_programas, container, false);
        Progs_List = new ArrayList<>();
        programaSrecyclerAdapter = new PROGRAMASrecyclerAdapter(Progs_List);

        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.Recycler_ProgramasList);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(programaSrecyclerAdapter);

        firebaseFirestore.collection("programasdatarde").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                if (queryDocumentSnapshots == null){
                    String error = e.getCause().getMessage();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Empty QUERY: "+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{

                    for (DocumentChange doc: queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){

                        if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){

                            ModelProgramas modelProgramas = doc.getDocument().toObject(ModelProgramas.class);
                            Progs_List.add(modelProgramas);
                            programaSrecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

I know the problem is not in the fragment class nor the adapter, I mean I THINK, because I have reviewed them over and over again, and I have other fragments with recyclerviews which execute the same functions and they don't present this kind of error.

PLEASE DONT MARK THIS AS DUPLICATE QUESTION FOR I HAVE WORKED OUT ALL THE OTHER SOLUTIONS ON OTHER RELATED POSTS BUT IT DOESNT SOLVE MY ERROR! PLEASE HELP.

And the data structure is like this.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your database structure?

Comment: And yes, are you sure that the other values are retrieved properly? And is it crashing? Is it displaying none of your items? Please answer these questions.

Comment: Yes the other values are retrieving as desired, no it does not crash, it displays all of them except the one above, wich is the first item on the model class, i had have encountered this problem before, but then just changed the name of the variable in the model class and in the database and it suddenly worked, but the one thing i noticed is, IT DOES THIS ONLY OR MOST OFTEN TO THE FIRST VARIABLE IN THE CLASS, i dont know if it matters but thats what i've noticed

Comment: Okay. And the database structure?

Comment: i posted the link above, i snapped the document name and the fields its in a collection

Answer (score 0):

I found an error and several improvement in your code, which are as follows.

Remove the `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`. Because your `RecyclerView` is loaded dynamically and you might not have a fixed height for each of your element.

Do not call `notifyDataSetChanged` inside a for loop. Do it like this.

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("programasdatarde").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

        if (queryDocumentSnapshots == null){
            String error = e.getCause().getMessage();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Empty QUERY: "+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            for (DocumentChange doc: queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){
                if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                    ModelProgramas modelProgramas = doc.getDocument().toObject(ModelProgramas.class);
                    Progs_List.add(modelProgramas);
                }
            }

            // Move the notify data set out here. 
            programaSrecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
```

Now simplify your model class. I think you do not need explicit getters and setters. Just declaring the variables as public will do. However, the getters and setters are okay. I could not find any errors there.

```
public class ModelProgramas {

    public String sabado;
    public String evento;
    public String responsavel;
    public String data;
    public String horario;

    public ModelProgramas() {}
}
```

Please make the changes and check if the error still persists. However, I could not find any problem with your adapter and model class. The suggestions that I tried to put here are moving out the `notifyDataSetChanged` out of the loop and removing the `setHasFixedSize` attribute from the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: ok will do, and ill be back in a second. some suggested that when some methods are not used(setters in model class) Proguard eliminates them, thus not found by firestore, but if it were so then the other setters should also be deleted and not found.